# Socket.io in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

Here's how I'm listening to notifications from socket.io in reactjs:

```js
render(){
  var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');  
  socket.on(isAuthenticated().user._id, function(msg){
    toast.info(msg)
  });
  const {deal, supplier, buyer, info,user, shipment, payment} = this.state;
  return(
    ....
  )
}
```

Everything is working fine. I see that the notification is emitted just once from the server side yet it is getting rendered 6 times on the client side. How do I limit it?

Comment: You shouldn't have side effects such as `io` and `socket.on()` in your `render` method. You should use `componentDidMount` for that. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount and make sure you add `componentWillUnmount` too, to clean up any event listener you created in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Can you share code how do I use componentWillUnmount? Because Im still getting multiple notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have side effects such as `io` and `socket.on()` in your render method.
You should use `componentDidMount` for that. It is invoked immediately after a component is inserted into DOM. See [this link](http://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for information about `componentDidMount` and make sure you add `componentWillUnmount` too, to clean up any event listener you created in `componentDidMount`, as it is invoked just before a component is removed from DOM.

After you initialize your socket event listener in `componentDidMount` by using the `on` method, you need to clear the event listener in `componentWillUnmount` by calling the `off` method. `socket` inherits all methods from `Emitter` ([click here for more information](https://github.com/component/emitter)) which defines the `off` method which you need to use in `componentWillUnmount`.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/component/emitter#emitteroffevent-fn):

> Pass `event` and `fn` to remove a listener.
> Pass `event` to remove all listeners on that event.
> Pass nothing to remove all listeners on all events.

So in your case, you could just use `socket.off()` without parameters to remove all socket listeners. Or `socket.off(isAuthenticated().user._id)` to remove all event listeners for that specific event.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Dejan Janjušević's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62952977/6474744), you can implement the `useEffect` hook for cleaner code. There's a [nice blog post on `useEffect` react hook here](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2020-04/use-effect/), and [the official SocketIO documentation on using it with react hooks](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-hooks) if you're curious.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";

function App() {

  // [...] states, etc.
 
  // only when the entire page (re)loads
  useEffect(() => {

    // Establish connection
    setSocket(io('http://localhost:8000'));

    // Handle events
    socket.on(isAuthenticated().user._id, function(msg){
        toast.info(msg);
    });

    // Clean up
    return () => {
      socket.off(isAuthenticated().user._id);
    };
  }, []);

  // [...] some business logic

  return(
    [...] what needs to be done and rendered
  );
}

export default App;
```